# Months displayed incorrectly when using ggplot2

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, formatting

Hi having a problem where March appears twice in my graph but not in my Data.

My data looks like. My data frame is called try1.

```
    Month                 Year    tcol
   2016-01-01 00:00:00    06      1461.0
   2016-02-01 00:00:00    06      259.5
   2016-03-01 00:00:00    06      191.2
   2016-04-01 01:00:00    06      151.5
   2016-05-01 01:00:00    06      119.6
   2016-06-01 01:00:00    06      1372.5
   2016-07-01 01:00:00    06      954.0
   2016-08-01 01:00:00    06      1784.0
   2016-09-01 01:00:00    06      1369.0
   2016-10-01 01:00:00    06      6077.0
   2016-11-01 00:00:00    06      1638.0
   2016-12-01 00:00:00    06      3308.0
```

And my code looks like.

```
ggplot(try1, aes(Month,tcol)) + 
       geom_point(aes(colour = Year),size=2) + 
       geom_line(aes(colour = Year), size=0.73)+
       theme_bw()+
       guides(col = guide_legend(ncol = 2))+
       scale_x_datetime(
                        breaks=date_breaks("1 months"), 
                        labels=date_format("%B"))+
       xlab("")+ #x axis label 
       ylab("Total Coliforms")
```

The problem is that when I plot my graph March appears twice. And October appears to be left out.

[The resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYhPW.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what data type is the Month column? Factor or date?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.  Could you run `dput(try1)` and copy the result into your question.  That will we are working with the same classes of objects.

Comment: @9Heads, your month labels are off by 1 month; they start with December and end in November).  Not quite sure how you accomplished that. :)

Comment: @Benjamin It was fault of the default time zone which it was taking instead of my system time zone. After the correction [Link of the plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tHvKD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is a timezone issue.  E.g., with this data

```
structure(list(Month = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), mon = 0:11, year = c(116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 
116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L), wday = c(5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
0L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L), yday = c(0L, 31L, 60L, 91L, 
121L, 152L, 182L, 213L, 244L, 274L, 305L, 335L), isdst = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("GMT", 
"GMT", "GMT", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", 
"GMT", "GMT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
"zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = c("Europe/London", 
"GMT", "BST")), Year = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L), tcol = c(1461, 259.5, 191.2, 151.5, 119.6, 1372.5, 
954, 1784, 1369, 6077, 1638, 3308)), .Names = c("Month", "Year", 
"tcol"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can reproduce your chart.  Try changing the timezone

```
attr(try1$Month, "tzone") <- "UTC"
```

and replot.

---

*Update.* I was wondering why changing the timezone to "UTC" works. It turns out that `date_format()` takes a `tz` argument that defaults to "UTC".  See `?date_format`.  This means that instead of changing the timezone of `Month` to "UTC", you can also fix your problem by changing the `tz` argument in `date_format()` to whatever the original timezone of `Month` is, which you can inspect via `attr(try1$Month, "tzone")`.

Comment: It's Indeed a timezone issue. I plotted the data above with my system time zone and got the correct graph. [Link of the plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tHvKD.png)